# angular 2 MockBackend test http timeout?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, rxjs, angular2-testing

Is there a way to test http timeout behaviour of a service?

I'm using MockBackend even when setting job's timeout to 0 no logging of 'TIMEOUT' present.

```
export class MyHttpService {
private sendGetRequest (job: HttpJob): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(job.getUrl(), this.options)
      .share()
      .timeout(job.getTimeout(), () => this.requestTimeout(job))
      .catch((err) => this.errorHandler(err, job));
  };

  private requestTimeout(job: HttpJob): Error {
    job.errorCode = ErrorCode.TIMEOUT;
    console.log('TIMEOUT');
    return new Error('timeout');
  }
...
```

test (nothing is logged)

```
 it('should resolve to TIMEOUT', () => {
      job.timeout = 0;
      let response: any;
      service.sendRequest(job).subscribe(
        (res: Response) => {
          response = res.json();
          console.log('OK', res);
        },
        err => {
          response = err;
          console.log('ER', err);
        }
      );
      expect(job.errorCode).toEqual(ErrorCode.TIMEOUT);
    });
```

Thx!

**update**: [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/ZXxSCrD7), if timeout is uncommented, it will fail

Answer (score 1):

It's because the resolution of the `subscribe` method is asynchronous. You are trying to test synchronously.

```
it('..', () => {
  doSomthing().subscribe(() => {

  })
  expect(something)
})
```

Here, he expectation happens synchronously before any asynchronous tasks triggered by the subscription. And the test completes synchronously even before the asynchronous tasks are complete (that's why you never see the console.log)

What you need to do is either use `async` and do the expectation in the subscription callback

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'

it('..', async(() => {
  doSomthing().subscribe(() => {
    expect(something)
  })
}))
```

Or use `fakeAsync` and force a fake synchronous resolution by calling `tick`

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing'

it('..', fakeAsync(() => {
  doSomthing().subscribe(() => {
    // this is called when you tick
  })
  tick();
  expect(something);
}))
```

Comment: you are right wrapping test in async(..) got me next, however now if  `doSomthing()` contains `timeout(30000, new Error('....'))` in observable chain I receive this error: `Cannot use setInterval from within an async zone test`. How could I test http timeout?

Comment: That's right, `setInterval` can't be called from `async`. Maybe `fakeAsync` also. And `timeout` calls `setInterval` internally. Not sure what you can do. Let me think about it. Im pretty sure it will fail also, but try to use `fakeAsync`

Comment: OK I think I got the solution. Instead of either of those, just use the jasmine native `done`. `it('..', ((done) => {`, and call `done` inside the callback, after you make the expectation. I imagine that should work

Comment: I tried that with `done()` but now i get this error `function (){__cov_eKH4RcGaeeuwa1xb1U0Ipg.f['9']++;__cov_eKH4RcGaeeuwa1xb1U0Ipg.s['33']++;return _this.requestTimeout(job);}` my `requestTimeout ` method is not called instead metioned err is catched in my `errorHandler` method

Comment: Not sure. I would need a complete test to check it out

Comment: test with the service: http://pastebin.com/AdTmMdHx, please take a look..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128334/discussion-between-petr-marek-and-peeskillet).

Comment: minimal example...pastebin.com/ZXxSCrD7
if timeout is uncommented, it will fail..