# angular 2 unit testing with karma and jasmine, how to simulate offline and timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

Is there a way to utilise testing angular2 app's behaviour in offline, specifically http requests? Some way to mock offline response maybe.

How could one test http request timeouts? I already asked question regarding this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644626/angular-2-mockbackend-test-http-timeout), but could not solve though (updated).